# Sending 2 Dimensional Array between Activities with Bundle not working

Tags: java, android, arrays

Alright Here is a better Description of my problem i guess the first one was a little vague and hard to understand.
I have this DataSheet0, that consists of several arrays called, MeetingNames,TopicNames and TopicTimes. They are all String arrays!

```
 String[][] DataSheet0 = new String[][]{MeetingNames,TopicNames,TopicTimes};
```

I now need to send this Array to my 2nd Activity called OpenMeeting.class
This is my attempt at it, i dont know whether its working or not because i cant receive it, i guess i have to bundle it? How?

Send with:

```
  Intent OpenMeeting = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OpenMeeting.class);
  OpenMeeting.putExtra("Meeting Data",DataSheet0);
  startActivity(OpenMeeting);
```

Want to receive with:

```
  String[][]DataSheet;
  Intent DataFromMainActivity = getIntent();
  DataSheet = DataFromMainActivity.getSerializableExtra("Meeting Data");
```

The receiving part throws me an error, because the array is no serialzable object. Could you write me the solution code of sending the 2 dimensional array with a bundle and how to unbundle it back to the original 2 dimensional array!

**EDIT**
I tried so solve it this way. Now it doesnt throw any errors. But Where is the Data out of Array in now? Is the original 2 dimensional array now saved in the same order in the new String[][] Datasheet from the receiving part?

Send it With

```
Intent OpenMeeting = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OpenMeeting.class)
            Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
            mBundle.putSerializable("Meeting Data",DataSheet0);
            OpenMeeting.putExtras(mBundle);
```

Receive it With

```
 String[][] DataSheet = null;
    Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("key_array_array");
    if(objectArray!=null){
        DataSheet = new String[objectArray.length][];
        for(int i=0;i<objectArray.length;i++){
            DataSheet[i]=(String[]) objectArray[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not getting the question. Please add the data type of items added into the bundle.

Comment: Alright I Rewrote my problem for it to be understandable :/. I Hope you can help me with this and write me some example code to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to put a model with meetingNames, topicNames, topicTimes as variables in it and create an `ArrayList` of the model and send/ receive it across.

Comment: Could you Give me an example of how to do that. I am pretty new and not that used to Array Lists yet :/

Comment: Just googled a random post. http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9 Just look at ListModel asyour bean and checkout the code where they create and use ArrayList<ListModel> in this example.

Comment: Well Thank you very much. You brought me the idea to actually split the 2d array up into simple arreays and swap them out with a switch. But i haven't found a way to send a 2D Array or a 2D arraylist. But Thank you!